# SQL get products of each category with OFFSET / FETCH

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query to print 10 product with each category

```
WITH MyRowSet AS (SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.cateID ORDER BY p.cateID DESC) 
        AS RowNum 
        FROM Product p )  
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyRowSet WHERE RowNum <= 10
```

Then I want to get the next 100 products with OFFSET / FETCH. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `order by` clause to specify which rows to fetch and which to offset:

```
WITH MyRowSet AS (SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.cateID ORDER BY p.cateID DESC) 
        AS RowNum 
        FROM Product p )  
SELECT * 
FROM MyRowSet 
WHERE RowNum <= 10
ORDER BY p.cateId, rownum
OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```